# How to compose a search query for lucene.net?

Tags: lucene.net

Just wonder not finding a good example of doing custom search over multiple fields having different value in each?

I have following need:

category:cat1 country:usa state: california desc:some text title:some text

the problem is I am new to lucene and unable to understand how to compose the above query so the search is accomplished!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you have one search query for each field in the index? And you want an `AND` clause between these?

I think you should be able to create a BooleanQuery to accomplish this;

```
...
var directory = FSDirectory.Open("PATH_TO_INDEX");
using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory))
{

    var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    Query category = new TermQuery(new Term("category", searchTextForCategory));
    Query country = new TermQuery(new Term("country", searchTextForCountry));
    Query state = new TermQuery(new Term("state", searchTextForState));
    ...

    booleanQuery.add(category, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(country, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    booleanQuery.add(state, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    Hits hits = searcher.Search(booleanQuery)
    ...

}
```